# Yodlee MFA flow

Tags: yodlee

I need your help regarding MFA flow. Could you tell me please if there is a list of institutions, that use MFA, or if it is possible to get it?

I have found site, that looks like it had MFA, at least it has such data within response (siteSearchString)

```
"mfaType":{"typeId":4,"typeName":"SECURITY_QUESTION"},"mfaCoverage":"FMPA"
```

But when I'm getting site login form with this siteID, I'm getting simple login form with

```
"isMFA": false
```

When I try to addSiteAccount using this siteId, I'm getting this error:

```
{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException",
  "referenceCode": "_23e71a23-4298-4d86-9271-be9ada8892b0",
  "message": "Multiple exceptions encapsulated within: invoke getWrappedExceptions for details"
```

}

Looks like, that this call requires real credentials for this institution. Am I right? If so, is there any test banks or other financial institution, that use MFA? So we can use them in development mode and not to interact with real ones?

I have found useful [generator](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Sample_Data/Yodlee_Dummy_Account_Generator). So question with test accounts is solved.

Please correct me if I miss something in MFA flow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `isMFA: false` value present in the login form does not make a site MFA.

`"mfaType":{"typeId":4,"typeName":"SECURITY_QUESTION"},"mfaCoverage":"FMPA"` this value represents if a site is MFA or not.

The exception which you are getting is coming because the login form parameters are not passed correctly in the `addSiteAccount` API.

You should use [getSiteLoginForm](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteLoginForm) API to get the login form for a site and then construct the request of [addSiteAccount](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/addSiteAccount1)

Also I would suggest you to go through the [API flow](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account) to understand the sequence of API to be used correctly.

Comment: Hi Shreyans,

I have one more question regarding `putMFARequestForSite`. I successfully got response from `getMFAResponse`, but when I try to `putMFARequestForSite` I'm getting: `{ "primitiveObj":false }`
So looks like request wasn't successful. Could you please clarify what reason can be for that? I was using dummy account generator data fro this. Could it be that answers are incorrect?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. Since you are using getMFAResonse API, you will have to use putMFARequest and not putMFARequestForSite.